# Proof that $det \, {\bf F} = 1 + tr \bf \, H$ in a linearized setting, where $\bf F$ and $\bf H$ are deformation and displacement gradients

Tags: elasticity

I am looking for a proof of that the determinant of deformation gradient $\bf F$ in a linearized setting is

$det \, {\bf F} = 1 + tr \bf \, H$

Where $\bf H$ is the displacement gradient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nothing to do with deformations etc. There is  an expansion
$$
{\rm det}[{\mathbb I}+\epsilon A]= 1+\epsilon \,{\rm tr}[A]+ \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}\left(({\rm tr}[A])^2-{\rm tr}[A^2]\right)+\ldots.
$$
This expansion is obvious  in the case that $A$ is diagonal because
$$
\prod(1+\epsilon \lambda_i)= 1+\epsilon \sum_i\lambda_i+\ldots. 
$$
It is also  invariant under $A\to O^{-1} AO$, so holds true for any diagonalizable matrix -- and by some general arguments about algebraic relations that are true almost everwhere, holds true for all matrices.

Comment: What is this expansion called? I'd like to read a bit about it but can't find anything definite.

Comment: I don't think it has a name....  Perhaps a Fredholm expansion? There is a brief account in the subsection "Chern Weil theory" on the Wiki page for "Chern Class," But that is about davanced stuff and this undergraduate linear algebra.